# Not able to access share path

Tags: windows-7

When I try to access a  network share path in Windows 7 I am getting  the following error

```
The specified server cannot perform the requested operation
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will happend with many causes
But many of this error is related to domain and dns
Sure the computer name is unique or you can try to access pc with ip . Refer to ip 
As enter in run \your ip
Sample :
1-windows menu cluck on run
2- enter ip for example \192.168.0.2
And feedback result of them